# Difference in cost result between Sklearn and manual implementation of logistic learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I have been trying to replicate the logistic regression model with sklearn results. There seem to be having some minor difference in the cost. I think there would be some mistake.

Here is the code from Sklearn:

```
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.30)
classifier = sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression(max_iter = 10000)
classifier.fit(X_train,Y_train)
function = np.dot(X_train, classifier.coef_.reshape(-1,1)) + classifier.intercept_ - Y_train.reshape(-1,1)
activation = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-function))
cost =   np.sum(-(Y_train.reshape(-1,1) * np.log(activation) + (1-Y_train.reshape(-1,1)) * np.log(1-activation)))/Y_train.shape[0]
print(cost)

cost = 0.09494712120076532
```

My attempt of replicating logistic regression model manually:

```
## My Logistic Model:

## Preprocessing
ones_train = np.ones((X_train.shape[0],1)) # Vector of ones for train X
ones_test = np.ones((X_test.shape[0],1)) # Vector of ones for train X
X_train_rev = np.concatenate((X_train,ones_train),axis = 1) # Append Intercept column in the training X data
X_test_rev = np.concatenate((X_test,ones_test),axis = 1) # Append Intercept column in the test X data
Y_train = Y_train.reshape(-1,1) # Reshape Y_train
Y_test = Y_test.reshape(-1,1) # Reshape Y_test
m = X_train_rev.shape[0]
n = X_train_rev.shape[1]

# Paramaterization

alpha = 0.001 # Learning_Rate

# Initilization

coefficient = np.random.randn(1,n) # Initialisation of coefficients including intercept

# Update Gradients
for i in range(10000):
    Z = np.dot(X_train_rev, coefficient.reshape(-1,1))  - Y_train.reshape(-1,1) # Compute Z
    A = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-Z)) # Compute A
    cost =   np.sum(-(Y_train.reshape(-1,1) * np.log(A) + (1-Y_train.reshape(-1,1)) * np.log(1-A)))/X_train_rev.shape[0] # Compute cost
    if i % 1000 == 0: print(cost) # Print cost
    grad = np.dot((A - Y_train).T,X_train_rev) # Compute Gradient
    coefficient = coefficient - (alpha * grad) # adjust coefficients including intercept
    

Cost after 1000th iteration:
1.4916689930810232
0.0875458497191988
0.0875181643157349
0.08751717663190926
0.08751704000862144
0.08751701549904194
0.08751701099400619
0.08751701016449238
0.08751701001176625
0.08751700998365015
```

It is observed that there is a minor difference of 0.01 approximately between Sklearn and my manual implementation. I guess this is considered to be a big difference in ML. I re ran the code multiple times and it gives the cost from manual implementation to be approx. 0.01 lower than what Sklearn provides.

Here are the coefficients learnt by the two model. They are quite different:

[image: Coefficient from manual and sklearn logistic model]

Thank you all

Comment: sklearn isnt a "standard" logistic regression: from the docs "Note that regularization is applied by default" https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html

Comment: I tried C to be large value say 1e42 to nullify the effect of regularization in sklearn but still there was 0.05 difference between my manual code and Sklearn.